# Setting default audio capture device (Particular microphone)

Tags: c#

I want to set particular microphone a my default sound recording microphone in C#.net.

If i have two or more sound capturing device i want to set as i requred.

Please suggest any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [AudioLib](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/AudioLib.aspx?q=AudioMixer+code+project).